# Not following how to test broadcast events in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-events

So consider the following event:

```
class UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets;

    public $count;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(int $count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('approved-clinician-count');
    }
}
```

Nothing complicated here.

So according [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#event-fake) this is how I am suppose to test this event:

```
public function testBroadCastShouldEmit() {
    Event::fake();

    $count = 1;

    Event::assertDispatched(UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent::class, function ($e) use ($count) {
        $e->count === $count;
    });
}
```

But I get:

> Tests\Unit\Health\Datasets\Builders\UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEventTest
>   x  broad cast should emit [0.360s]
>
> Time: 503 ms, Memory: 30.00 MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1)
>   Tests\Unit\Health\Datasets\Builders\UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEventTest::testBroadCastShouldEmit
>   The expected
>   [App\Modules\Clinics\Events\UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent]
>   event was not dispatched. Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> /Users/xxx/Documents/health/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/EventFake.php:62
>   /Users/xxx/Documents/health/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
>   /Users/xxx/Documents/health/tests/Unit/Modules/Clinics/Events/UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEventTest.php:31

**So, how do you test broadcast events?** Am I suppose to call the event? Does this dispatch method call it for me? *Like I am confused*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#dispatching-events):

> To dispatch an event, you may pass an instance of the event to the
>   event helper. The helper will dispatch the event to all of its
>   registered listeners. Since the event helper is globally available,
>   you may call it from anywhere in your application:

```php
event(new UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent($count))
```

And the test would be as follows to assert it was dispatched:

```php
public function testBroadCastShouldEmit() {
    event(new UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent(1))
    Event::assertDispatched(UpdateApprovedClinicianCountBroadcastEvent::class)
}
```

Comment: You cannot just call a broad cast event the way you are, they have to be faked because when I do it, it's trying to physically send out a broad cast and it fails with an exception. How ever faking it does not work because it never gets dispatched.